# mail: "Connection timed out"

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, gmail

Since some days there are errors on outgoing mails to gmail , log :

```
Nov  5 19:19:19 root postfix/smtpd[505]: warning: hostname root.***.de does not resolve to address 178.***.**.***
Nov  5 19:19:19 root postfix/smtpd[505]: connect from unknown[178.***.**.***]
Nov  5 19:19:19 root postfix/smtpd[505]: 59B2A9FE4B: client=unknown[178.251.228.148], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=no-reply@***.de
Nov  5 19:19:19 root postfix/cleanup[517]: 59B2A9FE4B: message-id=<b7fc54e81df63ff7d9f02d022c98c294@***.de>
Nov  5 19:19:19 root postfix/qmgr[1332]: 59B2A9FE4B: from=<no-reply@***.de>, size=1377, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  5 19:19:19 root postfix/smtpd[505]: disconnect from unknown[178.251.228.148]
Nov  5 19:19:42 root postfix/smtp[32549]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.189.27]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  5 19:19:49 root postfix/smtp[751]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.133.27]:25: Connection timed out
```

Whats that? gmx, yahoo and so on works. Something is preventing outgoing email, does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? It's only gmail... I'm using postfix on my debian 8 vserver. here one output of a "test" :

```
root@vps:~# traceroute -n -T -p 25 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
traceroute to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (74.125.133.27), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  178.**.***.1  5.384 ms  5.382 ms  5.354 ms
2  * * *
(skip identical lines)
30  * * *
```

Comment: My best guess is some kind of reverse lookup failed.

Comment: I checked here and I get its confirmed : https://www.debouncer.com/reverse-dns-check

Comment: Do you need further help or can you fix it yourself now? You always learn more fixing things yourself.

Comment: ? there is still the problem , one reason it could be is cloudflare , some days ago my website were down due to cloudflare ...

Comment: Cloudflare is typically very reliable. With regards to email your MX entries aren't proxied by CloudFlare, it just acts as regular DNS, so shouldn't cause any problems with email.